# change from mySQL to SQL and now cant get record creation

Tags: php, sql, insert

I am running WAMP 2.5 on Win7 and created a webpage to insert records into a mySQL database. This worked perfectly.
Then I needed to use SQL Server 2014 (remote server on LAN) instead of mySQL (local in WAMP), and while everything seems ok, i am not getting the records created in the table, yet no error either.
Account used to log in with is db owner.
Any help would be great.
Thanks
Len

Code is as follow (I call sqlconnect.php for db connection) and get confirmation that connection was successful.
File is called insert-data.php so it calls itself if form is empty and Submit is selected.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['mcpbarcode'])) {
    header("Location insert-data.php");
    include('sqlconnect.php');

    $mcpbarcode = $_POST['mcpbarcode'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO mcpbarcode (mcpbarcode)
                    VALUES ('$mcpbarcode')";
sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlinsert);
    if (!$sqlinsert)    {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }
    $newrecord = "New record added";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Insert Barcode into Database</title>
</head>
<h3><font color = red>This window must be open and active</font></h3>
<img src="header.jpg" alt="anyname" style="width:800px;height:165px;">
<body>
<h1> Insert barcode into Database</h1>
<form method="post" action="insert-data.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
<label>Barcode:<input type="text" name="mcpbarcode" autofocus /></label>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add new record" />
</form>
<?php
$newrecord="";
echo $newrecord
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: short answer. either use mysqli or pdo and then implement prepared statements.

Comment: Also why do you have this line `header("Location insert-data.php");`?? That should leave this script. also you missed the `header()`location syntax

Comment: What is the error? Is mcpbarcode the column name for which you provide the data?
What are the other columns in the table?

Comment: To check if there is an error - use `if (!sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlinsert))    {`

Answer (score 0):

See if it's working like that:

If mcpbarcode column is a string type (varchar, char etc):

```
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO mcpbarcode (mcpbarcode)
                    VALUES ('".$mcpbarcode."')"
```

OR if mcpbarcode column is int, float, etc:

```
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO mcpbarcode (mcpbarcode)
                    VALUES (".$mcpbarcode.")"
```

but you should have an error on mysql also ...